# Azure Function Targeting .NET Core 2.2

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I created a new `Azure Functions` app using `Visual Studio 2019` and looks like it's targeting `.NET Core 2.1` -- see below:
[image]

I have all the updates installed on my machine, including `.NET Core SDK 2.2`.

How do I get `Azure Functions` template in `Visual Studio 2019` to target `.NET Core 2.2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change that value to netcoreapp2.2 it will target 2.2 - however you can’t change the template to choose that by default as the template is the same for everyone and 2.1 comes by default with VS and didn’t want the template to only work with a few.

But you could also save as your own personal template in VS or make the change as necessary